# Accessing JPA-methods via inheritance and type parameterized repository

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

Say I have an abstract entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    protected String name;

}
```

with some kind of AbstractRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractRepository<C extends AbstractEntity> extends JpaRepository<C, Integer> {}
```

that's supposed to serve as a single dependency for multiple entities. The entities extend the abstract entity and thus the AbstractRepository:

```
public interface RealEntityRepository extends AbstractRepository<RealEntity> {}
```

In my service I want to use jpa inheritance to get rid of a bloat constructor (it's bloat because of too many realEntityRepos) and method implementations per entity. So instead of x methods like this per each entity

```
void findRealEntity(RealEntity entity) {
    entity.setId(realEntityRepository.findOne(entity.getName())
            .map(RealEntity ::getId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(entity.getName())));
}
```

I want to have only one method call like in the following pseudocode (I know one cannot instantiate abstract classes) that takes the entity as an abstract entity for an argument, invokes the child's repo and executes the jpa methods in that specific child repo.

```
void findEntity(AbstractEntity entity) {
entity.setId(abstractEntityRepository.findOne(entity.getName())
        .map(AbstractEntity::getId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(entity.getName())));
```

}

This is my service as of now, it does work like that but it's bloat:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

private final RealEntity1Repository realEntity1Repository;
private final RealEntity2Repository realEntity2Repository;
private final RealEntity3Repository realEntity3Repository ;
... 5 more times ..

public SomeService(RealEntity1Repository realEntity1Repository, RealEntity2Repository realEntity2Repository,
                            RealEntity3Repository realEntity3Repository,
 ... 5 more) {
    this.realEntity1Repository = realEntity1Repository;
    this.realEntity2Repository = realEntity2Repository;
    this.realEntity3Repository = realEntity3Repository;
    ... 5 more
}
... some methods

void findRealEntity1(RealEntity1 entity) {
entity.setId(realEntity1Repository.findOne(entity.getName())
        .map(RealEntity1::getId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(entity.getName())));
}

void findRealEntity2(RealEntity2 entity) {
entity.setId(realEntity2Repository.findOne(entity.getName())
        .map(RealEntity2::getId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new SomeException(entity.getName())));
}
...
```

**UPDATE**

Thx to @Antoniosss' hints i solved the problem!

Add `Optional<C> findByName(String name);` to SuperRepository
then create a new service that implements the entity repository specific transaction methods. Call this service in the previous service when implementing the mapping between AbstractEntity and entity specific methods:

```
public void mapAbstractEntity(AbstractEntity abstractEntity) {
  if (abstractEntity instanceof RealEntity1 { // call RealEntity1 method from service}
  else if (abstractEntity instanceof RealEntity2) { ... }
```

Comment: eeee why not use `findById` ??.....

Comment: i don't have the id, i search for names by an Example.Matcher

Comment: is that name named `name` everywhere?

Comment: yes it is named like that everywhere

Comment: `findByName` then.

Comment: there's no findByName and findOne can't be called on an abstrac class. i want the method to take the entity instance as an argument, invoke the super repository with the entity class to search in the specific entity repository for its intance example.

Comment: You just have to add that method and it will work (can do that in super interface). Method names are translated into queries.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, i've adjusted my question

Comment: So you want to have `findByName(T someEntiyHavingName)`?

Comment: it's not really about the method per se, it's about accessing any method starting from the abstract repository

Comment: Based on actual code - you can add `findByName` generic method to abstract repository, create map  that maps entity type to repository and than use single implementation of `findRealEntity(AbstractEntity)` that would select proper repository and call `findByName` on it.

Comment: hey @Antoniossss thx for sticking with me, you gave the right hints. don't you want to state your comment as an answer so i can reward you for the correct answer?

Comment: Sure, why not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on actual code - you can add `findByName` generic method to abstract repository, create map that maps entity type to repository and than use single implementation of `findRealEntity(AbstractEntity)` that would select proper repository and call `findByName` on it.